# About CppWinRT internal

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm learning the internal of CppWinRT

```cpp
struct App : ApplicationT<App,IXamlMetadataProvider>
{
  App()
  {
    IInspectable ins = *this;                        // A
    cout << to_string(get_class_name(ins)) << endl;
  }
  ...
}
```

why the output is `Windows.UI.Xaml.IApplicationOverrides`? In my understanding, code at A should fail, since there is no conversion operator defined in `producers`, that is, no such thing like

```cpp
// base.h (v2.0.190620.2 line 5707)
operator producer_ref<Windows::Foundation::IInspectable> const() const noexcept
{...}
```

Please help me to figure out the conversion path. Many thanks!!!

Comment: C++ has a pretty poor diagnostic story when it comes to templates (or overload resolution in general). To figure out what the compiler is doing, you'll need to introduce a bug, and have it list the candidates it considered. Try something like `IInspectable ins = this;` instead and see, if the compiler output gives you some hints. That said, the line marked `// A` is correct and should compile.

Comment: do not work, the compiler(cl) just say ```error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'App *' to 'winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable```

Comment: Finding the "correct" error is a challenge itself. Maybe `IInspectable ins = *(App const*)this;` produces the desired diagnostic output. Or changing the interface on the left-hand side to one you aren't deriving from.

Comment: I know there is a conversion sequence of ```producer_ref<IApplicationOverrides>```->```IApplicationOverrides```->```IInspectable```, but there is also a sequence of ```producer_ref<IApplicationOverrides2>```->```IApplicationOverrides2```->```IInspectable```, why compiler choose the first one?

Comment: Because `IApplicationOverrides` is listed before `IApplicationOverrides2` in the base classes of `ApplicationT`.

Comment: I tried with ```struct A {};
struct B : A{};
struct C : A{};
struct D : B,C{};

int main()
{
  D d;
  A a = d;
}```, compiler failed with ```error C2594: 'argument': ambiguous conversions from 'D' to 'const A &'```

Comment: C++ inheritance and COM inheritance aren't the same thing, and they follow different rules. Navigating a WinRT type's interface hierarchy boils down to explicit function calls (exposed as `as<>` and `try_as<>` in C++/WinRT), providing tools to disambiguate any sort of ambiguity.

Comment: But in this case, ```as``` or ```try_as``` are not involved, are they? Could you please show me the calling sequence?

Comment: You can single-step through your code in a debugger, or inspect the generated assembly code. Either one allows you to observe the operations performed when navigating the interface hierarchy.

Comment: Lol, found it at line 6930 ```operator IInspectable() const noexcept```